# Apache Internal Error 500 on PHP syntax errors (htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, internal-server-error

Recently something changed on my server, which has been causing an `internal error 500` to be thrown everytime there is a syntax or logical error in PHP. These errors are handling in the `exception class` and I dont want them throwing the `500` error.

*Forgot To Mention : when the page doesnt exist => 404 errors work just fine*

I current have error_reporting on to strict.
I am thinking it could be my `apache config file`

```
 <Directory /var/www/public/>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(http|https|ftp):\/\/(.*)
    #RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=rfi:true]
    #RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
    #CustomLog /path/to/logs/rfi.log combined env=rfi
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/404.php
    #ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domain.com/403.php
    ErrorDocument 500 http://www.domain.com/500.php
 </Directory>
 <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

**Does anyone see anything that might be causing the 500 error?**

Comment: Have you checked the error logs for the source of the error?

Comment: It happens when there is a syntax error, or an invalid object instance. I know exactly why it happens, but I want to avoid showing an internal error page. I was trying to redirect with my apache2 file, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A syntax error cannot be caught by PHP.  If a file can't be parsed, you'll get an unavoidable 500 error.  You can setup your php.ini to not display the errors on the client, but it will still log the error.

To suppress all errors from being sent to the client, in the php.ini file set

display_errors = Off

When a 500 error is encountered they'll just see a white blank screen.

There is no way to email you when this happens outside than having some script monitor your apache an php error logs.  You might be able to set a error.php file to show on 500 error by configuring it in you htaccess file, but i dont know.  If you can, you could put some basic php email code into that, but it would be generic--it couldn't tell the actual error.

Comment: that exactly what I'm looking for, how would I do that? (I just want to avoid the 500 error entirely) Also an additional question to that : How would I be able to send an email on an this kind of encounter?

Comment: I already had it set to `display_errors = Off`, any other ideas?

Comment: Well, to start if you have an error in your .htaccess file there's nothing you can do to prevent a 500 from being thown and visually displayed.  The second thing I'd check is to see if you're using a framework, library, or have a file that's manually turning on the display_error directive on php.  You can do it anywhere by  `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: This would display the errors to the user.. I have them handled in a `try` `catch` block, but it seems when a `class instance` is created, it throws a 500 error

Comment: @mlishn unless im mistaken, you can't catch parsing errors when a class file is loaded.